# Converting Characters to ASCII Code & Vice Versa In C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, character-encoding, c++-cli, type-conversion, ascii

I am currently learning c++/cli and I want to convert a character to its ASCII code decimal and vice versa( example 'A' = 65 ).

In JAVA, this can be achieved by a simple type casting:

```
   char ascci = 'A';
   char retrieveASCII =' ';
   int decimalValue;
   decimalValue = (int)ascci;
   retrieveASCII = (char)decimalValue;
```

Apparently this method does not work in c++/cli, here is my code:

```
   String^ words = "ABCDEFG";
   String^ getChars;
   String^ retrieveASCII;
   int decimalValue;

   getChars  =  words->Substring(0, 1);
   decimalValue = Int32:: Parse(getChars);
   retrieveASCII = decimalValue.ToString();
```

I am getting this error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Any Idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please explain what result you want to get.

Comment: I need to find the ASCII code of given characters, I am getting the characters from a textBox and I need to convert them to their ASCII Code and then display it on a labelBox.

Comment: `char ascci = 'A'; int n = (int)ascii;`

Comment: This type of conversion does not work in C++/CLI .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters in a `TextBox::Text` property are in a `System::String` type. Therefore, they are Unicode characters. By design, the Unicode character set includes all of the ASCII characters. So, if the string only has those characters, you can convert to an ASCII encoding without losing any of them. Otherwise, you'd have to have a strategy of omitting or substituting characters or throwing an exception.

The ASCII character set has one encoding in current use. It represents all of its characters in one byte each.

```
// using ::System::Text;

const auto asciiBytes = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(words->Substring(0,1));
const auto decimalValue = asciiBytes[0];   // the length is 1 as explained above

const auto retrieveASCII = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(asciiBytes);
```

Decimal is, of course, a representation of a number. I don't see where you are using decimal except in your explanation. If you did want to use it in code, it could be like this:

```
const auto explanation = "The encoding (in decimal) " 
                       + "for the first character in ASCII is " 
                       + decimalValue;
```

Note the use of `auto`. I have omitted the types of the variables because the compiler can figure them out. It allows the code to be more focused on concepts rather than boilerplate. Also, I used `const` because I don't believe the value of "variables" should be varied. Neither of these is required.

BTW- All of this applies to Java, too. If your Java code works, it is just out of coincidence. If it had been written properly, it would have been easy to translate to .NET. Java's `String` and `Charset` classes have very similar functionality as .NET `String` and `Encoding` classes. (Encoding to the proper term, though.) They both use the Unicode character set and UTF-16 encoding for strings.

Answer (score 1):

More like Java than you think

```
String^ words = "ABCDEFG";
Char first = words [0];
String^ retrieveASCII;
int decimalValue = ( int)first;
retrieveASCII = decimalValue.ToString();
```